# Screens HTML element sizes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I got xd.adobe link from the designer to implement it as web pages, so I'm taking the same px sizes that exist in adobe and putting them to my web page HTML elements, but what I noticed is the HTML elements look more zoomed-in in bigger screen, so if the screen is matching the screen sizes in xd.adobe the webpages will be identical otherwise it will be bigger, I read one of the solution is to stop using px and start using %, but will not be applicable because the project will be finished after a couple of days.

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to convert the **px** to any other sizing units, than I would suggest that you do so using **rem** unit. Basically **rem** unit is relative to the size of html root tag.
To further understand it I recommend you to go through this site.
[Link](https://pixelsconverter.com/px-to-rem)

Here is an example of conversion:

```css
* {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

#first {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <p id="first">My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My second paragraph.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

And its equivalent css in **rem**:

```css
* {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.125rem;
}

#first {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <p id="first">My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My second paragraph.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so you mean once I start using rem everywhere on the web pages that will give me uniform screen sizes on different screens?

Comment: rem won't give you the best responsive website but it will still be better than % and far more better than px. I recommended rem to you because you need to replace all the px measures in your already built website and rem would be the easiest way to do it. An even better way would be to use units like vh, vw and vmax. See the documentation for the same to know more.